# List all keys in Utimaco HSM created by PKCS11 and CNG?

Tags: hsm, pkcs11

Is there a way to list all keys inside the Utimaco HSM, created by PKCS11 interface and `cngtool`?
currently, I only can view each of them separately:

PKCS11: using "PKCS#11 CryptoServer Administration" interface.

CNG keys using the command: `cngtool ListKeys`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general PKCS#11 question, but it relates to a specific vendor and how this vendor implemented different APIs. Therefore, primary contact point would be their support.

In this case, PKCS#11 and CNG use the vendor's proprietary API CXI and, therefore, all keys can be listed using cxitool (given that you have a user with the proper rights).

Comment: I forgot to mention the vendor, edited the question

Comment: I know :) The product name was unambiguous. However, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I tried the `cxitool` yesterday, it somehow works, it lists all user's keys regardless of the key origin.

Comment: But sounds like there are restrictions to list ALL keys inside the HSM

Comment: Access to keys is restricted by the user attribute CXI_GROUP that must match the group of the key. Read e.g. the cxitool manual section "Cryptographic Keys and Key Groups".

Comment: "the cxitool manual section"! didn't find any resources, the only thing I could find is an archived file that only has a command, I learned using the tool from it! Can you share the manual with me please?

Comment: Download the SecurityServer simulator from Utimaco's homepage. It contains all documentation.